# Function undeclared error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, function

Can you spot the error, please? Why does the compiler think my function is undeclared? Thanks. -Rob

In .h file

```
-(int) getW:(int)xPosition;
```

In .m file

```
-(int) getW:(int)xPosition {
    return (xPosition-58)/48; 
}
```

in another procedure, the call to the function:

```
whichTile=[getW: xPosition] ;   <----ERROR getW undeclared (first use in this function)
```

(xPosition and whichTile have been declared as integers, and in use earlier in the procedure). I tried it with (NSInteger), too (and a million other permutations!). Thanks for you help.-Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have declared an instance method and called it without specifying the instance.

for example:

```
whichTile = [self getW:xPosition];
-or-
whichTile = [anObject getW:xPosition];
```

unlike other languages, `self` is not implicit when messaging.